# saving the images to a folder with custom filenames

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and need assistance. I am performing segmentation with my own medical data set. The test images in my folder are named like "1.0.2.34.56_1.png". I would like to remove the actual image extension and append the image names with "_mask.png". The current code throws an error.

```
def labelVisualize(num_class,color_dict,img):
    img = img[:,:,0] if len(img.shape) == 3 else img
    img_out = np.zeros(img.shape + (3,))
    for i in range(num_class):
        img_out[img == i,:] = color_dict[i]
    return img_out / 255

def saveResult(save_path,npyfile,flag_multi_class = False,num_class = 2):
    for i,item in enumerate(npyfile):
        img = labelVisualize(num_class,COLOR_DICT,item) if flag_multi_class else item[:,:,0]
        io.imsave(os.path.join(save_path,"%d_mask.png"%i),img) 
saveResult("data/membrane/test/",results)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the code you provided doesn't do much to help your actual problem of renaming the files. I will just focus on tha tpart by showing you how to get the filenames you want.

You can rename the files, as you describe them, like this - assuming you have a list of filenames that match your description.

```
filenames = ['1.0.2.34.57_1.png', '1.0.2.34.58_1.png', '1.0.2.34.59_1.png']

for file in filenames:

    # Do what you want with the file...
    # Image processing and modelling, etc.


    # Replace the extension with your custom ending
    final_filename = file.replace('.png', '_mask.png')
```

---

Another way to do it, breaking down the removal and addition into two steps

```
for file in filenames:
    file_without_ext = file.replace('.png', '')

    # Add you custom ending
    final_filename = file_without_extension + '_mask.png'

    # Another variant - joining the extension to the file_without_ext using "_"
    final_filename = '_'.join(file_without_ext, 'mask.png')
```

The three variants of `final_filename` will be identical.

Now you can save the output of your image processing using the `final_filename`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the code below to take images using OV2311 and RPI Zero w. However, I don't want my previous image to be overwritten.

I therefore request for help from experts here.

import arducam_mipicamera as arducam
import v4l2 #sudo pip install v4l2
import time

def set_controls(camera):
try:
print("Reset the focus...")
camera.reset_control(v4l2.V4L2_CID_FOCUS_ABSOLUTE)
except Exception as e:
print(e)
print("The camera may not support this control.")

```
try:
    print("Enable Auto Exposure...")
    camera.software_auto_exposure(enable = True)
    print("Enable Auto White Balance...")
    camera.software_auto_white_balance(enable = True)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

if **name** == "**main**":
try:
camera = arducam.mipi_camera()
print("Open camera...")
camera.init_camera()
print("Setting the resolution...")
fmt = camera.set_resolution(1920, 1080)
print("Current resolution is {}".format(fmt))
# print("Start preview...")
# camera.start_preview(fullscreen = False, window = (0, 0, 1280, 720))
set_controls(camera)
time.sleep(1)
frame = camera.capture(encoding = 'jpeg')
frame.as_array.tofile("{}x{}.jpg".format(fmt[0],fmt[1]))

```
    print("Setting the resolution...")
    fmt = camera.set_resolution(3280, 2464)
    set_controls(camera)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Current resolution is {}".format(fmt))
    frame = camera.capture(encoding = 'jpeg')
    frame.as_array.tofile("{}x{}.jpg".format(fmt[0],fmt[1]))

    # Release memory
    del frame
    # print("Stop preview...")
    # camera.stop_preview()
    print("Close camera...")
    camera.close_camera()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```